# INSERT с неизвестным количеством полей

Tags: sql-server, sql

Возникла потребность вставки в некую таблицу, инфу о таблице беру отсюда INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
Сначала я узнаю имена полей, типы данных.
Вопрос: как сгенерить соответствующий INSERT запрос?
Процедурка.

Comment: Мне кажется, что генерирование запроса лежит вне языка SQL. Нужны дополнительные ресурсы, надстройки (PL) и прочие языки программирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил сам. Создал переменную `@inert` типа `varchar`. Наполнил ее `@insert = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES ("qwerty", "qwerty2")'` и выполнил `EXEC(@insert)`. Все оказалось гораздо проще, чем думал. )

Comment: Имейте в виду, что на подобный трюк нужны права вставки в таблицу у вызывающего процедуру пользователя. Они бывают не всегда.

Comment: Все учтено, я просто совсем забыл про exec().